# HTML5 Tag/Attribute For Excluding Content From <article>

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Is there some way to make it clear to webcrawlers/bots that something included in an article or section is not relevant to the article?

```
<article>
    <section>
        <div>
            <span>Amy Neville</span>
            <img src="http://www.example.com/amy.png">
            <span>Joined <time>5 Days</time> ago</span>
            <span>41525 Points</span>
        </div>
        <p>Mary, the only surviving legitimate child of King James V of Scotland, was six days old when her father died and she acceded to the throne. She spent most of her childhood in France while Scotland was ruled by regents, and in 1558, she married the Dauphin of France, Francis. He ascended the French throne as King Francis II in 1559, and Mary briefly became queen consort of France, until his death in December 1560.</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

In the example above I have a forum post. Next to it is a `<div>` with some irrelevant information about the person who posted it. Not relevant, but possible to get mixed up with the actual article content.

Is there any tag or attribute that can make this clear?

Comment: I wouldn't say an article's author is irrelevant, but do you mean it displays in Google search results?

Comment: This was just a general example for content inside an <article> that might not be relevant to the article. There are many cases where this happens.

Comment: [`<aside>`](http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/) might be of use?

Comment: Yes, I've been considering that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if a sectioning element contains information that *is* completely irrelevant to the content of that section, the closest you can get is with an `<aside>` element.

---

Information about the person who posted an article is relevant to the article in that it describes the author of said article. It does not form part of the *content* of the article, but it is relevant nonetheless.

Having said that, you can use either a `<header>` or `<footer>` to mark up author information within a sectioning element. You can even have a `<footer>` at the beginning of a section — it may seem strange but it's perfectly fine (see the [spec describing the `<article>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element)).

```
<article>
    <section>
        <footer>
            <span>Amy Neville</span>
            <img src="http://www.example.com/amy.png">
            <span>Joined <time>5 Days</time> ago</span>
            <span>41525 Points</span>
        </footer>
        <p>Mary, the only surviving legitimate child of King James V of Scotland, was six days old when her father died and she acceded to the throne. She spent most of her childhood in France while Scotland was ruled by regents, and in 1558, she married the Dauphin of France, Francis. He ascended the French throne as King Francis II in 1559, and Mary briefly became queen consort of France, until his death in December 1560.</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

There are no dedicated elements for marking up author information save from the `<address>` element, but `<address>` is intended for contact information.

Comment: oh really? I thought footer was just for the....footer....still getting used to this html5 stuff.

Comment: @Amy Neville: Yep, you can have a page footer, and you can have section footers as well. These usually contain stuff like date posted, tags, permalink, but can also contain author info.

Comment: This is perfect. I have this sort of things too so I will create headers and footers as well inside each section. And an aside for the profile info! :)